# List of Abbreviations like bibliography in biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex-sbl

SBLHS2 makes the list of abbreviations different than the bibliography for entries depending on whether the abbreviation is for the author or the title. This means that the abbreviation list looks different than the bibliography for certain entries.

Here is a MWE with two entries from SBLHS2.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}
   
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib} 
      
@book{BDF,
   author = {F. Blass and A. Debrunner},
   title = {A Greek Grammar of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature},
   subtitle = {A Translation and Revision of the Ninth-Renth German Edition Incorporating
      Supplementary Notes of A. Debrunner},
   shorthand = {BDF},
   editor = {Robert W. Funk},
   editortype = {reviser},
   translator = {Robert W. Funk},
   publisher = {The University of Chucago Press},
   address = {Chicago}, 
   year = {1961}
}  
   
@mvlexicon{TLNT,
   title = {Theological Lexicon of the New Testament},
   shorthand = {TLNT},
   shorttitle = {TLNT},
   volumes = {3},
   author = {Ceslas Spicq},
   translator = {James D. Ernest},
   publisher = {Hendrickson Publishers},
   date = {1994},
   address = {Peabody, MA},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill

\printbiblist{abbreviations}
Cite BDF.\footcite[1]{BDF} Cite TLNT.\footcite[2]{TLNT}

\clearpage
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Basically, it looks like SBLHS2 always puts the thing abbreviated first in the entry in the list of abbreviations, author/editor or title. `biblatex-sbl` is doing just like SBLHS2 requests (an example of TLNT in the bibliography is given in 6.3.6 in SBLHS2 and looks just like this).

My style guide is slightly different, in that the entries in the list of abbreviation should look just like a bibliography entry. How can I make the entry in the abbreviation list look just like a bibliography entry?

Comment: The SBL Blog has changed things to prefer abbreviations to look like the bibliography too. I've been avoiding fixing this because I keep hoping I will get around to making progress on version 2. Let me see what I can do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news. I think this can be adjusted pretty easily. It's controlled with a toggle, which we can just remove from the `abbreviations` driver:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{abbreviations}
  {\toggletrue{blx@abbrevcite}}
  {}
  {}
  {}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib} 
@book{BDF,
  author = {F. Blass and A. Debrunner},
  title = {A Greek Grammar of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature},
  subtitle = {A Translation and Revision of the Ninth-Renth German Edition Incorporating
     Supplementary Notes of A. Debrunner},
  shorthand = {BDF},
  editor = {Robert W. Funk},
  editortype = {reviser},
  translator = {Robert W. Funk},
  publisher = {The University of Chucago Press},
  address = {Chicago}, 
  year = {1961}
}  
@mvlexicon{TLNT,
  title = {Theological Lexicon of the New Testament},
  shorthand = {TLNT},
  shorttitle = {TLNT},
  volumes = {3},
  author = {Ceslas Spicq},
  translator = {James D. Ernest},
  publisher = {Hendrickson Publishers},
  date = {1994},
  address = {Peabody, MA},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{abbreviations}
  {\toggletrue{blx@abbrevcite}}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
Cite BDF.\footcite[1]{BDF} Cite TLNT.\footcite[2]{TLNT}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks again!